# Change default Xib file in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, xib

I am currently developing an app in Xcode 4 for Mac, and would like to change the default xib file opened when starting the application.
How should I proceed ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main nib file can be specified in the Info.plist key `NSMainNibFile`. By default it is `MainMenu.nib`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, just found it. In the Project properties / Info, change the "Main nib file base name".